# Tensorflow model learns in Colab - not locally

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Something interesting is happening - I was playing with Keras examples (DDIM more specifically), and after many trials the loss function does not go down at all.

I copied and pasted the exact code to Colab and it learns super fast in a few epochs. Here is a link to the code. https://keras.io/examples/generative/ddim/

The only difference between the two is that I had to specify the location of some Cuda lib because it couldn't find it locally.

```
import os
os.environ[
    "XLA_FLAGS"
] = "--xla_gpu_cuda_data_dir='C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v11.7'"
```

And before the training starts, it shows the following logs:

```
2023-06-27 14:08:48.972686: I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/tensorflow/utils/dump_mlir_util.cc:263] disabling MLIR crash reproducer, set env var `MLIR_CRASH_REPRODUCER_DIRECTORY` to enable.
2023-06-27 14:08:49.130489: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_compilation_cache.cc:478] Compiled cluster using XLA!  This line is logged at most once for the lifetime of the process.
```

Any ideas?

Edit

```
Local tf version: 2.9.1
Colab tf version: 2.12.0
```

Will try to update

Result

Installed `tf version 2.11.0` - started working right away